# Webpack authoring libraries import errors with TypeError: xxx is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, webpack

I am having trouble importing a javascript package I wrote (and published to npm) into a new project.

I created an ES6 package and bundled it using `webpack`. Within the package I can import the library using the bundled file using a script tag,

`<script src='../dist/awesome-table-dist.js'></script>`

then new up the class like so:

`let awesomeTable = new AwesomeTable.AwesomeTable('record');`

Works like a charm! [awesome-table](https://iannazzi.github.io/awesome-table/)

I pushed the package up to npm, now I want to bring it into a new project like so:

`import AwesomeTable  from '@iannazzi/awesome-table'`

then

`let awesomeTable = new AwesomeTable('record');`

which is erroring:
`TypeError: _iannazzi_awesome_table__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default.a is not a constructor`

Now that I am importing it to a new project I have tried a variety of ways new up the class,  but seem completely stuck.

I can use the package by including the script again, but obviously I want to import so I can re-package:
`<script src='node_modules/@iannazzi/awesome-table/dist/awesome-table-dist.js'></script>`

Here is the webpack configuration for the package:

```
var path = require('path');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");

const SRC_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname,'../src');
const DIST_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app: SRC_DIR + '/table/AwesomeTable.js'
    },
    output: {
        path: DIST_DIR,
        filename: 'awesome-table-dist.js',
        library: 'AwesomeTable',
        // libraryTarget: 'window'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader"],
            },
        ],
    },
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin('style.css')
        //if you want to pass in options, you can do so:
        //new ExtractTextPlugin({
        //  filename: 'style.css'
        //})
    ]
};
```

Comment: I think I have it, the `libraryTarget` needed to be `umd` in the package webpack config ... picky picky

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you need to expose your lib, you can do that via defining [`library`](https://webpack.js.org/guides/author-libraries/#expose-the-library) & `libraryTarget: 'umd'` properties.

Second, it is not recommended to publish lib as a bundle. Think about that scenario, You lib is composed from several parts, but not all of them are mandatory. When you ship your lib a a bundle, you are forcing your users to download redundant extra code.

The best practice today is to transpile your code via Babel to be compatible `es5` and `commonjs` as a module system.
Recently, there is a trend to ship es6 modules in a separate folder, so that whenever your users will use bundles that supports [tree-shaking](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/), they will able to use it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I did get it working by adding in libraryTarget. Where are you reading about module publishing practices? I seem to be stuck in one section of webpack docs

Comment: https://medium.com/webpack/webpack-and-rollup-the-same-but-different-a41ad427058c

Comment: https://medium.com/jsdownunder/rollup-vs-webpack-javascript-bundling-in-2018-b35758a2268

Comment: felixmosh thanks! I think what I have is actually not a library - it is one giant piece of code and all the parts are required. I have created a distributed bundle that I can use for testing the code in a browser within the package, and that same file can now be distributed with the `umd` flag correction. I was thinking it would be better for one of my main apps that is going to consume this to just ship out the source folder - it does not need to be bundled as that app is getting bundled. It sounds like you are confirming this thought process...

Comment: for completeness... this is the docs I have been following: https://webpack.js.org/guides/author-libraries/